# Get data by XPath in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

So I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<M_ChucVu>
  <ChucVu>
    <MaChucVu>1
    </MaChucVu>
    <TenChucVu>
    </TenChucVu>
  </ChucVu>
  <ChucVu>
    <MaChucVu>2
    </MaChucVu>
    <TenChucVu>
    </TenChucVu>
  </ChucVu>
  <ChucVu>
    <MaChucVu>23</MaChucVu>
    <TenChucVu>12</TenChucVu>
  </ChucVu>
  <ChucVu>
    <MaChucVu>44</MaChucVu>
    <TenChucVu>44</TenChucVu>
  </ChucVu>
</M_ChucVu>
```

and I want to retrieve the `ChucVu` tags that contain an empty `TenChucVu` tag so the result is this:

```
<ChucVu>
  <MaChucVu>1
  </MaChucVu>
  <TenChucVu>
  </TenChucVu>
</ChucVu>
<ChucVu>
  <MaChucVu>2
  </MaChucVu>
  <TenChucVu>
  </TenChucVu>
</ChucVu>
```

Comment: just to confirm, you want the `<ChucVu>` tags in which the child `<TenChucVu>` tag is blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another XPath that should work

```
/M_ChucVu[./ChucVu/TenChucVu='']
```

for example

```
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(yourXmlString);
        var elem = doc.DocumentElement;
        var sel = elem.SelectNodes("/M_ChucVu[./ChucVu/TenChucVu!='']");
        // print or use sel.InnerXml
```

Comment: That would select a different set of elements (`M_ChucVu`), not `ChucVu` as requested...

Comment: It gives what the op wants when used in an XmlElement.SelectNodes().  I've added an example to make it clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
XDocument doc = ...;
var query = doc.XPathSelectElements("//ChucVu[TenChucVu='']");
```

Answer (score 2):

The XPath you need is:

```
/*/ChucVu[not(string(TenChucVu))]
```

or

```
/*/ChucVu[string-length(TenChucVu)=0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as:

```
  string xparth = String.Format("//ChucVu[TenChucVu='{0}']", '');
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("Xml");
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode(xparth);
            XmlNodeList list = root.SelectNodes(xparth);
```